# Regular expression for matching n amount of parenthesis

Tags: regex

I need to parse expressions of the following form:

(S (A (B (D xyz)) (C m)))

The amount of ( will always equal the amount of ), but there may be any arbitrary number of opening and closing parenthesis pairs between the (S ). In this case, I would want to extract the (A (B (D xyz)) (C m)). There may be any number of (S ) clauses in a file, so I can't simply do a ^(S .* )$ kind of pattern matching.

If I knew the amount of potential opening and closing parenthesis pairs between the (S ) this wouldn't be as difficult, but I'm not sure how to write a regular expression that will know to match an arbitrary amount of ().

Any help in obtaining the regexp pattern would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done in theory, and can be done in practice only when maximal number of nested parentheses is known upfront. That solution requires a rather non-pleasant expression, and is usually attempted as a curious homework exercise. Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx) with better explanation of why regexp language is not powerful enough to solve the matching parentheses problem.

You need a parser to solve this problem; a simple [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) one will do the trick. Wikipedia article at the link above has a sample implementation in C, which you should be able to translate to other languages with relative ease.

Comment: "even in theory" -> I think this should simply be "in theory". Practical regexes tend to be more powerful than theoretical regexes; for instance aⁿbaⁿ cannot be recognized by a finite automaton either, but some regex implementations match it as (a*)b\1 or somesuch.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You are right, I removed the "even" part, and mentioned that there are solutions when the maximal number of nestings is known upfront. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Matching an arbitrary number is impossible with pure regular expressions.  In other words, you can not match a count that it is unknown when you're generating/writing the regular expression is impossible.  Matching `n` pairs (however high `n` is) is possible as long as you know `n` when generating the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a record descent parse would be the best bet. But if you just want to find (S) balanced, it could be done with a regex that does recursion in the engine.

It will find the outter most balance. If you were looking to nesting like (S(S)) that might involve recursively calling a function that implements the regex, passing the 'core' of a sucessfull match. And possibly creating a parent-child structure in the process. But if its this involved, a real parser might be the solution.

How it can be solved with a Perl regex -

```
$str = '(some (stuff  (S (A (B (D xyz)) (C m))) the end ) (S extra))';

$regex = qr~
[(]
\s* S \s*
(                   # 1
    (                       # 2
      [(]
      (?:  (?> [^()]+ ) 
        |  (?2)                                         
      )*                                               
      [)]
    )
 |
    [^)]*
)
[)]
~x;

while ($str =~ /$regex/g)
{
    print "found '$1'\n";
}
```

prints

```
found '(A (B (D xyz)) (C m))'
found 'extra'
```