# How to extract substring using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Here's my regex pattern to extract just the "annotation:(...)"

```
annotation\s?:\s*?\((.*)\)
```

From

```
AND annotation:("Asthma UK" OR "Health and Social Care (Safety and Quality) Bill" OR "General Medical Council") AND NOT org("Dark Knight")
```

But unfortunately, it matches,

```
annotation:("Asthma UK" OR "Health and Social Care (Safety and Quality) Bill" OR "General Medical Council") AND NOT org("Dark Knight")
```

However, I want to just match

```
annotation:("Asthma UK" OR "Health and Social Care (Safety and Quality) Bill" OR "General Medical Council")
```

Any help to improve the above regex pattern is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?:
`annotation:\("(.*)"\)\s`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
(annotation\?*?:\s*?.+\"\))(?=\s*?AND|OR( NOT)? \w+\()
```

https://regex101.com/r/FQdrcu/1

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off situation, you can use something short and sweet like:

```
annotation:\("(.*)"\)\s
```

It works because in this case the part you are interested in ends with a double-quote and parentheses followed by a space before continuing into the text you do not want included. Check out the explanation at a site like: https://regex101.com/

If you need a more general case for other input strings, it's tempting to count matching parentheses, but that is not easy in regular expressions (see [Regular expression for matching n amount of parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622302/regular-expression-for-matching-n-amount-of-parenthesis))